# Failure to Locate Stationary Point in GAMESS

Tags: computational-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I'm currently trying to optimize the geometry of a complex using GAMESS at the B3LYP level. However, I keep failing to converge the SCF. I've already tried the following:

1. increasing the number of iterations up to 300
2. increasing the convergence criteria up from 0.0001 to 0.0005
3. Switching on DAMP
4. Switching DIIS on and off.
5. Switching off SOSCF

I'm out of ideas. What else can I do? It's interesting to note that I'm testing the ligand against 3 metals: Copper, Zinc and Iron. While Copper and Iron fail to converge, Zinc converged on my first try. Would it be fair to say that given the same ligand, the complex I've designed is "impossible"?

Thanks!

Comment: Lot of unknowns right now.  Firstly, check your charge and multiplicity.

Comment: @LordStryker Interesting. I'm using Cu(II) which has a multiplicity of 2 and a charge of +2. My ligand is neutral and has no unpaired electrons, so MULT=2 ICHARGE=2. For Fe(III), the same thing applies, so MULT=2 ICHARGE=3. Or am I mistaken somehow?

Comment: @BernardJudeGutierrez The Fe(III) could be high-spin, depending on the ligand, so your actual multiplicity might be 6. (Intermediate-spin, with MULT=4, is uncommon, but also possible.) There might well be static correlation junking up the works for both Fe(III) and Cu(II), though I've rarely had SCF convergence issues with the Cu(II) species I've computed. Zn(II) has a closed d-shell, so it's a much less complex electronic system to work with; not surprising it's behaving better.

Comment: @hBy2Py thanks for the input. I'll try a couple of iterations on the Iron. I'm not sure how the ligand will affect the spin of the metal since this is a novel complex anyway. Would you say I should also try the same for Copper?

Comment: What's your basis set? B3LYP is already suspect for a potentially multiconfigurational problem like Fe(III). SOSCF is most useful once the DIIS error goes down, which can be hard with a bad guess. Damping is not as useful as one would think. Something better is to converge SCF in a small basis, then project to the larger desired basis, but I don't know if GAMESS can do that.

Comment: You could, sure. Shouldn't take long to tell if it's going to work better. AFAIK copper is always MULT=2 in 'normal' complexes, but if your ligand is exotic enough in the right ways, it might converge at MULT=4? If it does converge at 4, then you should definitely see if there's a stable broken-symmetry wavefunction.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon I'm using B3LYP //631G(d). I use this because I've successfully modelled the ligand using this basis set. I'll try to see if I can do it with PM3. I'll also try SOSCF.

Comment: @hBy2Py, I've tried every iteration of multiplicities and they all still fail to converge. Maybe there's something wrong with the basis set? PM3 returns "Gradient out of Range" for this ligand.

Comment: Let's move to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70169/optimiszing-optimiszing).